# Does here api allow enabling traffic in calculateRoute function

Tags: android, here-api

Can I enable traffic information when specifying the route options in calculateRoute function? I'm using here sdk in my application

This is my caclulateRoute function

```java
final RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();                   
routeOptions.setTruckLength(25);                                        
routeOptions.setTruckHeight(5);                                         
routeOptions.setTruckWidth(2.5f);                                       
routeOptions.setTruckLimitedWeight(40);                                 
routeOptions.setTruckWeightPerAxle(10);                                 
routeOptions.setTruckTrailersCount(1);                                  

RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();                                  
routePlan.setRouteOptions(routeOptions);                                

for (GeoCoordinate coordinate : locations) {                            
    RouteWaypoint routeWaypoint = new RouteWaypoint(coordinate);        
    routePlan.addWaypoint(routeWaypoint);                               
}                                                                       

CoreRouter coreRouter = new CoreRouter();                               
coreRouter.setConnectivity(CoreRouter.Connectivity.DEFAULT);            
coreRouter.calculateRoute(routePlan,.......
```

I was asking is there any way to specify that we should consider traffic information also while calculating route.

Comment: can you please elborate in more detail

Comment: please see my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the Premium SDK (since you refer already to Core router anyway):

The CoreRouter has a method:

setDynamicPenalty(DynamicPenalty penalty)

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/DynamicPenalty.html

One of the "penalty" modes is TrafficPenalty:

setTrafficPenaltyMode(Route.TrafficPenaltyMode mode)

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/DynamicPenalty.html#setTrafficPenaltyMode-com.here.android.mpa.routing.Route.TrafficPenaltyMode-

Setting the traffic penalty mode to OPTIMAL is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. 
```coreRouter.setDynamicPenalty(Route.TrafficPenaltyMode.OPTIMAL);```
is this what you mean? 

But I'm getting an error 
com.here.android.mpa.routing.DynamicPenalty can CoreRouter cannot be applied to com.here.android.mpa.routing.Route.TrafficPenaltyMode

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. But one step inbetween is probably missing: setDynamicPenalty takes a DynamicPenalty instance, not trafficPenaltyMode directly. Create a dynamicpenalty, and the  setTrafficPenaltyMode(Route.TrafficPenaltyMode mode) there.

Comment: Okey!! Thanks a lot @Marco 

```DynamicPenalty dynamicPenalty = new DynamicPenalty();              dynamicPenalty.setTrafficPenaltyMode(Route.TrafficPenaltyMode.OPTIMAL);
                
CoreRouter coreRouter = new CoreRouter();
coreRouter.setConnectivity(CoreRouter.Connectivity.DEFAULT);
coreRouter.setDynamicPenalty(dynamicPenalty);
coreRouter.calculateRoute(routePlan,....```


This worked!!